# How to use regex to match all element in document.doctype.internalSubset

Tags: javascript, regex, doctype

By using document.doctype.internalSubset, I have the following string, say **str**:

```
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
```

Then, I use **regex** to extract the result:

```
result = regex.exec(str);
```

My **expected output** is an array in which:

```
result[0] = owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
result[1] = xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
...
result[3] = rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
```

So, I create this regex:

```
var regex = /(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)*/g;
```

And here is the result, of course, it's not I want:

```
owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the errors, and how to fix all of them ?

Note that I can use **s.indexOf()** to get the position of **`<!ENTITY`** and **>**, and then, use **s.subString()** to get the same result, but I'm learning regex now, so I want to use regex.

**--------------Update---------------**

Thanks to Supr, I can finally figure out the error, it seems to me that, in this case, "*" doesn't mean "match one or many time", so instead of using `/(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)*/g`, we'll use this one: `/(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)/g` (supress the *) and then loop over the string until we get all result. Here is the source:

```
var str = '<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >' 
    + '<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >' 
    + '<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >'
    + '<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >'

var regex = /(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)/g;
var results = []; 

while ((result = regex.exec(str)) != null) {
    results.push(result[1]);
}
console.log(str);
console.log("-------------------------------");
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    document.write(results[i] + "<br>");
}
```

For testing: http://jsfiddle.net/nxhoaf/jZpHv/

By the way, here is my solution using s.indexOf() and recursion:

```
var str = '<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >' 
    + '<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >' 
    + '<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >'
    + '<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >'

var getNamespace = function(input) {
    var result = []; // Store the final result
    var temp = []; // Store the temporary result

    // Non trivial case
    if ((input != null) && (input.length != 0)) {

        // Get the begin and and index to extract the entity's content
        var begin = input.indexOf("<!ENTITY");
        var end = input.indexOf(">");

        if ((begin == -1) || (end == -1) || (begin >= end)) { // not found
            return null;
        }

        // Fix the begin index
        begin = begin + "<!ENTITY".length;

        // Get the content and save it to result variable
        var item = input.substring(begin, end); // ok, get one item
        // As end > begin, item is always != null
        item = item.trim(); // Normalize
        result.push(item);

        // Continue searching with the rest using
        // recursive searching
        temp = getNamespace(input.substring(end + 1)); 

        // Ok, collect all of data and then return
        if (temp != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                result.push(temp[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    } else { // Trivial case
        return null;
    }
}

// Parse it to get the result
result = getNamespace(str);
console.log("*************");
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    document.write(result[i] + "<br>");
}
```

you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nxhoaf/FNFuG/

Comment: You told us what you don't want, but didn't tell us what you want

Comment: What I want is in "My expexted result....": result[0] = owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#", and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New solution**

It seems like the last `*` makes the expression consume the entire string even though the return value only includes the first match. If you change your expression to `/(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)/g;`, then you can apply it multiple times. The regular expression object will keep track of where the last match ended and continue from there. So:

```
var regex = /(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)/g;
var results = [];
while (result = regex.exec(str)) {
  results.push(result[1]);
}
```

---

**Old and busted solution**

Try using `result = str.match(regex);` instead. From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns null.

Example from same doc

```
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var regexp = /[A-E]/gi;
var matches_array = str.match(regexp);

// matches_array now equals ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: I modified the regex to var regex = /(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)/g; (don't have the * symbol before /g anymore, the result is <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >, <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >....

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = Array();
```

pass the regular expression pattern

```
var pattern= /(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)*/g;  //your pattern

arr = string.match( pattern )
```

hope this will work for you ..access that array

Comment: may be you went wrong with your patter..try this var pattern= /(?:<!ENTITY(.*?)>)*/g;